# How to count referenced items in same table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

**Updated with new table definition**

I may be too tired to understand how to achieve the following. I have a table where items refer to each other within the same table. I would like to count how many references each item has.

To simplify I have defined a table of persons where the fathers are linked from their children. The table is created by following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS persons;

CREATE TABLE persons (
  id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  isfather  TINYINT,
  name      VARCHAR(20),
  father_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO persons (name, isfather, father_id) 
       VALUES ('John', 1, 0), ('Mike', 1, 0), ('Anne', 0, 1), 
              ('Peter', 0, 1), ('Jane', 0, 2), ('Olivia', 0, 1), 
              ('Max', 0, 2), ('Eric', 1, 0), ('Hugh', 0, 0);

SELECT * FROM persons;
```

This outputs the following table:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is a query that counts how many children each father has. I.e. John has 3, Mike has 2 and Eric has 0:

[image]

I have managed to create similar queries, but with two different tables (e.g. a parents table, and a children table). I used `SELECT DISTINCT(...), COUNT(...) FROM ... INNER JOIN`. But I cannot understand how to use a query with JOIN or similar on the same table. Note that a child must not have a parent, and a parent doesn't necessarily has a child. I have struggled so long now and my brain is tired to think clearly. I hope somebody can help :)

Comment: Is this guaranteed not to be recursive? As in, will there definitely be no fathers with a non zero father id?

Comment: @SimonBrahan It is not recursive... but I forgot one important thing. The fathers are identified clearly as fathers (i.e a child can exist without father, and a father may exist without children). I need to edit my post :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT father.name, COUNT(child.id) AS children
FROM persons AS father
LEFT JOIN persons AS child ON child.father_id = father.id
GROUP BY father.id
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` will get 0 counts for people without any children. Change to `INNER JOIN` if you don't need them.

Comment: I'll try this... Hope it works on my "real" table which is far more complex ;)

Comment: Add an index to `father_id` for performance.